# if(abs(num-num2)<=0.01) cout<<"XYyx"; not working in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm a novice programmer. With a c++ console program I want to calculate if two numbers is *almost equal*(difference between that 2 numbers have to be between *0.01*. That program gives correct result when that 2 numbers is *3* to *17.99*. But when the numbers is out of this range it doesn't work. Here is code:-

```
double num,num2;
while(cin>>num>>num2)
{
    if(abs(num-num2)<=0.01)
    {
       cout<<"The numbers are almost equal";
    }
}
```

and also I've tried this way:-

```
double num,num2;
while(cin>>num>>num2)
{
    if(num>num2)
    {
        if(num-num2<=0.01)
            cout<<"~";
    }
    else if(num2>num)
    {
        if(num2-num<=0.01)
            cout<<"~";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work either of these way. I've tested this with (17.99 , 17.88),(12.34 , 12.35),(3.01 , 3.00),(18.00 , 17.99),(2.99 , 3.00) and so on. And as I have said before it only work for those numbers which is in the range [3,18). But when I've tried with this code:-

```
double num,num2;
while(cin>>num>>num2)
{
   if(num>num2)
   {
      if(num2+0.01>=num)
      {
         cout<<"~";
      }
   }
   else if(num2>num)
   {
      if(num+0.01>=num)
      {
         cout<<"~";
      }
   }
}
```

it worked. But as we know mathematically:-

```
num-num2<=0.01  Or, -num2-0.01<=-num  Or, num2+0.01>=num
```

so that *num-num2<=0.01* is the same way of saying *num2+0.01>=num*. In the same method *num2-num<=0.01* is equivalent to *num+0.01>=num2*. So, why should the last way worked and not the first  2 way? I just can't discover the reason. So, guy, please help me. Help me to know why does this happen?

Note that:- I've declared what else I've to declare in order to make the program  work. Also this statement:-

```
using namespace std;
```

is used in the all codes above.

Comment: you need `fabs()`, not `abs()`

Comment: @Slava Or just `std::abs`.

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are using `abs()` from C and as you can see from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) it accepts values of type `int` so your arguments are rounded. You either need to use `fabs()` from there or better C++ variant `std::abs()` which provides proper [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)

This yet another case that tells you "`using namespace std;` is not your friend"

Comment: Ohh, OK that is the thing, why not first code is not working. But why the second code isn't working, please find out the reason. And I always use 

"using namespace std;".

Comment: @Curiouslearner And I always use "using namespace std;". - then you better stop.

Comment: @Curiouslearner "But why the second code isn't working, please find out the reason" First of all one question per question. Second - [mcve] and sample of data is required (what you expect and what you get) read the rules.